# I am designing an Resource management tool. Design issue

Tags: java

In this one i have developed one pojo class for employee. In that a property called projectStatus is kept. ProjectStatus is another pojo class with three pojo classes as instance viriables in it as bench, block, assign.

```
 class Empoloyee{
    private String empId;
    private ProjectStatus projectStatus;
    private Project projectId;
 }

 class ProjectStatus{

    private Bench bench;
    private Block block;
    private Assign assign;
 }
```

When Resource manager creates a employee profile the default state of the employee is bench. How to acheive this using java?

What should be the relation between employee and project status.

Any bench employee can be blocked by an Resource manager, blocking indicates the state changes from bench to block and block state is for two weeks. What ever the pojo classes i have created are right or wrong ? please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a solution would be to create `ProjectStatus` as an `enum` instead of a POJO.

```
public enum ProjectStatus {
    BENCH, BLOCKED, ASSIGNED
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I will follow you. When in doubt, i will approach you guys.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep status (bench/block/assign) as POJO then you shall have a super interface Status, implement that in other status

```
public interface Status {}
public class Bench implements Status{}
public class Assign implements Status{}
public class Block implements Status{}
public class Employee {.. Status status;... }
```

Then you can assign any of the status to the employee as below

```
emp.setProjectStatus(new Bench());
```

Or Simply you can declare ProjectStatus as enum

```
public class Employee {
private enum STATUS {bench,block,assign};}
```

**EDIT**
Sample code using enum for ProjectStatus

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  public enum Status {
    bench, block, assign
  }

  private int employeeId;
  private Status status;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
  }

  public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
  }

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('bench', 'block','assign')")
  public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
  }
```

Table Structure ( for MySQL)

```
create table employee (
employee_id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
status enum('block','bench','assign') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'bench',
PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks faizal. I do have one more concern that is when an bench person is clicked to block how to make his status to block ? What must be the relation between Employee and status in hibernate ? As you told enum in Employee Class how it can be made relation in hibernate hbm file.

Comment: @Faizal, i have to create tables for block, bench and assigned. Block and Assigned belong to same sub set. I mean assigned means, a employee who is blocked can be assigned into a project. A person who is blocked will be in blocked state for two weeks and after that automatically he will be released to bench.